# Consume ado.net data service from a non-dotnet-3.5 client

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services

What are my options to access a ado.net data service from a .net 2.0 client?  The client application has to run on Windows 2000 so upgrading to .net 3.5 is not an option.

Other than writing my own proxy against the service, any other options out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that in this case you'd have to construct your own proxy, constructing your own http requests etc (perhaps via `WebClient`). Thankfully, creating a REST request is a lot easier than raw SOAP, as is parsing the result.

However, I wonder if consuming an `asmx` service (i.e. .NET 2.0 web-service) wouldn't be more pragmatic. If the ADO.NET Data Services service is out of your control, perhaps host a .NET 3.5 wrapper on another server that shims between `asmx` and Astoria? (i.e. exposes the data from the REST service via a 2.0 web-service).

Comment: I like the asmx approach.  will give it a try!
Thanks a lot for the suggestions!